# Linq select values from multiple lists inside a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of lists that contain `IntPtr` variables like this

```
var testList = new List<List<IntPtr>>();
```

I'm trying to select`IntPtr` variables from the lists where the size of the list is greater than 0 and the `IntPtr` does not equal `IntPtr.Zero` using Linq

I have tried the following

```
var pointers = testList.Where(list => list.Count > 0)
                       .SelectMany(pointer => pointer != IntPtr.Zero);
```

What exactly am I doing wrong and how could I modify this statement to get it to work as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you're passing a predicate to the `SelectMany` which is not what it expects; instead what it expects is a `Func<List<IntPtr>, IEnumerable<IntPtr>>` where `List<IntPtr>` is the input list and `IEnumerable<IntPtr>` is the value returned upon the function invocation.

`SelectMany` will then take each nested `IEnumerable<IntPtr>` and collapse it into a single `IEnumerable<IntPtr>`.

As well as that, you're also attempting to use the `!=` operator on a sequence (`List<IntPtr>`) represented by `pointer` which will not work.

Rather what you should do is first collapse the nested sequencs via `SelectMany` **and then** apply the predicate via a  `Where` clause:

```
var pointers = testList.Where(list => list.Count > 0) // IEnumerable<List<IntPtr>>
                       .SelectMany(list => list) // IEnumerable<IntPtr>
                       .Where(pointer => pointer != IntPtr.Zero); // IEnumerable<IntPtr>
```

On another note, you don't even need the first `Where` clause as it can simply be:

```
var pointers = testList.SelectMany(list => list) // IEnumerable<IntPtr>
                       .Where(pointer => pointer != IntPtr.Zero); // IEnumerable<IntPtr>
```